# how to use websocket in jhipster microservices architecture?

Tags: spring, websocket, jhipster

i try to trigger the websocket to push notification to client , but jhipster microservices doesn't support websocket in non-gateway service,
so i try to send the websocket message in a Gateway controller, and call this controller in other services with feignclient, but it seems doesn't work to call gateway controller in other service.

---

```
@PostMapping("/notify")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendNotification(@RequestBody TodoDTO todoDTO) {

        String dest = "/topic/notify/";
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(todoDTO.getTo())) {
            dest += todoDTO.getTo();
        } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(todoDTO.getToShopId())) {
            dest += todoDTO.getToShopId();
        } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(todoDTO.getToParentShopId())) {
            dest += todoDTO.getToParentShopId();
        }
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(dest, todoDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("SUCCESS");
    }
```

does anyone know the best practice when using websocket in jhipster microservices ?

Comment: You are correct the microservices do not support websockets, so the method you describe is one solution (and it works, I've used it in the past).  Something must be going wrong in your call to the feign clients.

Comment: i think the problem is :  the gateway is serve over https, and the other services server over http, the FeignClient try to call gateway through http instead of https...

Comment: when i try to change every services using https instead of http,  it doesn't work . it is worse, the gateway fail to communicate with other services ... doesn't jhipster-register support https? very strange

Comment: This is more of a Spring Cloud Config issue (probably dealing with Eureka), when your services use HTTPS I think they need special Eureka config.  Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824589/3737815 . Normally I recommend using a load balancer (such as nginx, haproxy, apache2) to terminate SSL which lets you scale the gateway and avoids this issue